# How do you specify Content-Type (and other headers) and request body in RSpec Rails Controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I'm trying to test a rails action that takes raw json in the POST body. If i curl with the Content-Type: application/json header set, rails parses the params correctly.

How do you set the request body and headers directly in an rspec controller test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In RSpec 1.3 you can operate on a "request" variable. Something like this should work for you:

```
request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
post :method_name
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, combined with settings the params in the request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']. Thanks.

Comment: 2 years later (2012-Nov-02), this does not work anymore. Does anyone have an updated way to force the request to be `json`? I was setting :format => :json, but this is not exactly what my clients are doing and I'm also trying to use fdoc to produce API docs which includes this extra parameter in every API (We ask clients to set the Accept header to `application/json`).

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039492/349423) for a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use 
post :method_name, { :format => :json, ... other parameter data }

Comment: This sets the 'Accept' header, not 'Content-Type'.