# Specifying Content Type in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack

I'm trying to build an rspec test that sends JSON (or XML) via POST. However, I can't seem to actually get it working:

```
    json = {.... data ....}.to_json
    post '/model1.json',json,{'CONTENT_TYPE'=>'application/json'}
```

and this

```
    json = {.... data ....}.to_json
    post '/model1.json',json,{'Content-Type'=>'application/json'}
```

any ideas? THANKS!

Comment: Usually you POST to an action in a controller. Why are you posting to a file?

Answer (score 20):

In Rails 3, you can skip the header and `@request.env` stuff and just add a `format` parameter to your post call, e.g.:

```
post :create, format: :json, param: 'Value of Param'
```

Comment: Does using `format: :json` set `request.accept` and `request.content_type` to `"application/json"`?

Comment: [This issue on rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/710) implies that `format: :json` is the same as `request.accept = "application/json"`.

Comment: It looks like in later versions of rails/rspec, `format: :json` got changed to `as: :json`

Answer (score 18):

There's a way to do this described in [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Testing-Controllers-with-respond_to--td16269121.html) -- it's a hack, but it seems to work:

```
@request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
json = { ... data ... }.to_json
post :create, :some_param => json
```

Comment: This works with Rspec 2 and rails 3. (and was extremely difficult to find)
Actually, I had to not use .to_json on the thing to get it to behave correctly. Otherwise, everything else worked fine.

Comment: Thank you. I had a hard-time searching for solution to my failing tests before reading your answer.

Comment: I also found that `request.accept = 'application/json'` will work as well.

Answer (score 10):

A lot of frustration and variations and that's what worked for me.
**Rails 3.2.12 Rspec 2.10**

```
 @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
 @request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
 put :update, :id => 1, "email" => "bing@test.com"
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out the one to work for me thanks to your answer: `@request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"`.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't want to test the built-in conversion of json to hash. Same applies to xml.

You test controller with data as hashes, not bothering wether it's json, xml or from a html form.

But if you would like to do that as an exercise, this is a standalone ruby script to do play with :)

```
require 'json'
url = URI.parse('http://localhost:3030/mymodels.json')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.content_type="application/json"
request.basic_auth('username', 'password')  #if used, else comment out

hash = {:mymodel => {:name => "Test Name 1", :description => "some data for testing description"}}
request.body = hash.to_json
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(request)}
puts response
```

to switch to xml, use `content_type="text/xml"` and

```
request.body = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><somedata><name>Test Name 1</name><description>Some data for testing</description></somedata>"
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more elegant test is to use the header helper:

```
header "HTTP_ACCEPT", "application/json"
json = {.... data ....}.to_json
post '/model1.json', json
```

Now this does exactly the same thing as setting `@env`; it's just a bit prettier.

Comment: Where is this method defined?  I get a NoMethodError when I try to call it.

Comment: @PaulBrannan It's [in rack/test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/master/lib/rack/test.rb#L134)

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have found to test these things is with request tests. Request tests go through the full param parsing and routing stages of Rails. So I can write a test like this:

```
request_params = {:id => 1, :some_attribute => "some value"}
headers = {'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
put "/url/path", request_params.to_json, headers
expect(response).to be_success
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can specify the headers with `headers` param:

```
post '/model1.json', headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Following the Rspec documentation of [how provide JSON data](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#providing-json-data).

Answer (score 0):

```
@request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
```

OR pass in request

`"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"`