# Rails 3.1 Rspec Rails 2 - How can I test this controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec-rails

I need to know how to test this controller action

```
  def create_mobile
      if mobile_user = MobileUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        session[:mobile_user_id] = mobile_user.id
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { head :ok }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { head :unauthorised }
        end
      end
  end
```

The route is a post request to sessions/create_mobile and as you can see the action only responds to json

My current controller spec looks like this

```
describe SessionsController, "Logging in" do

  before(:each) do
    @mobile_user = FactoryGirl.create(:valid_mobile_user)
  end

  it "Should log in mobile user" do
    @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
    post :create_mobile, {:password => @mobile_user.password, :email => @mobile_user.email}
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should fail log in mobile user" do
    @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
    post :create_mobile, {:password => 'joe', :email => @mobile_user.email}
    response.should_not be_success
  end
```

end

The test results in

```
  1) SessionsController Logging in should log in mobile user
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So there is either a problem with my application code or there is a problem with my test code but either way there is no problem with the authenticate method as the MobileUser model spec passes which looks like this

```
  it "should authenticate" do
    mu = FactoryGirl.create(:valid_mobile_user)
    assert_equal 1, MobileUser.count
    assert_equal mu, MobileUser.authenticate(mu.email, mu.password)

  end
```

Any help in sorting this out greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
As suggested below, using

`post :create_mobile, {:password => 'joe', :email => @mobile_user.email} :format => :json`

or using

```
@request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
```

or a combination of both makes no difference

**UPDATE 2**
The test has just started working for no reason that I can fathom (other than I never understood why it wasn't working in the first place).
Totally strange!

Comment: Instead of renaming this question "SOLVED," why not answer the question yourself or accept an answer here?  That way, future visitors to the site can see that there's a good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I met the same issue recently. below is my test code

```
post :create, :login => 'mock_user', :password => 'passwd', :format => :json

expected = {
    :login => 'mock_user'
}.to_json

session[:user_id].should == mock_user.id
response.body.should == expected
```

The test result is false, caused by response.body is blank. I checked the test.log, and found got 406 unacceptable request error in controller. After googled a lot, I changed to :format => 'json'. Then I got the expected test result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to post JSON to the controller, shouldn't you convert your hash to JSON?

```
post :create_mobile, {:password => 'joe', :email => @mobile_user.email}.to_json
```

If you don't want to add seven characters to your code just to see if it works, then you should output your params to logger to see what they look like.

```
def create_mobile
  logger.info "LOGIN PARAMS U/N: #{params[:email]}, P/W: #{params[:password]}"
  ...
```

Then tail -f log/test.log to see what your controller looks like during your test.

Comment: why? Controllers just accept a params hash I'm not decoding a json object

Comment: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "email=fred@somewhere.com&password=fred" http://0.0.0.0:3000/mobile_login works just fine

Comment: Because by looking at your spec, everything looks fine.  I don't know what your factory looks like, so I have to assume it's correct.  Plus, there was a similar issue on SO where that worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036748/specifying-content-type-in-rspec.  Plus, adding .to_json is fairly innocuous to try.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some basic troubleshooting steps you can take to see what your controller looks like while it's being tested.

Comment: For the record, I agree with you.  It doesn't make sense that you would have to do that.  Without more information, that's all I could come up with.

Comment: Well, here is the really odd thing. After tearing my hair out for 2 days on this it suddenly started working!!!! I know SOMETHING must have changed but I've checked out of source control various stages of the source code for both the web server and the android code and I am totally unable to reproduce the problem. I'm totally stumped as to the cause or the fix but it's working.

Comment: Just a quick follow up, This is more about returning a JSON response than sending a JSON object. I still don't know why this was failing or why it suddenly decided to work, the code has always worked outside of the test environment. I did re-boot my PC (very rare occurrence as I use UBUNTU) so maybe that cleared something up. I am suspecting a very rare and hard to reproduce bug in RSPEC or possibly even an OS fault. Anyway, thank you very much for your efforts with helping me to fix this. Your re-assurance that my code looked right was a big help. I was starting to doubt my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a `:format` option to the post statement