# Setting Content-Type header for RSpec and Rails-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-api

I'm using the [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) gem to build a web service and want to test my API with RSpec. Every request I make, regardless of the HTTP method has the `CONTENT_TYPE` header set as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". This isn't really a problem until I try to use [wrap_parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html#method-i-wrap_parameters) in my controller and it's not have any affect on the params hash:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters :project, include: [:name]
  # ...
end
```

[This hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036748/specifying-content-type-in-rspec) no longer works (@request is nil), and none of the other Stack Overflow posts I found work either.

If I make the following request in my RSpec test:

```
put "/projects/1.json", {name: 'Updated Project 1'}
```

and put a debugger in my controller I get:

```
(rdb:1) p params
    { "name"=>"Updated Project 1",
  "action"=>"update",
  "controller"=>"projects",
  "id"=>"5539bbd9-010c-4cfb-88d3-82dadbc99507",
  "format"=>"json"
}

(rdb:1) p request.content_type
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I'm expecting to see something like this for the params hash (note the addition of the project key):

```
{ "name"=>"Updated Project 1",
  "action"=>"update",
  "controller"=>"projects",
  "id"=>"5539bbd9-010c-4cfb-88d3-82dadbc99507",
  "format"=>"json",
  "project" => {"name" => "Updated Project 1"}
}
```

**Is it possible to set the content type header using just RSpec? Or do I have have to use  rack/test for this functionality?**

Comment: There's a chance that [wrap_parameters is still busted](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/issues/33) with the rails-api project and this has nothing to do with setting the content type.

Comment: Confirmed that wrap_parameters works by adding the :url_encoded_form format to method call: `wrap_parameters format: [:url_encoded_form, :json]`

Comment: You can set elements of the rspec request environment in a controller with `request.env['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'` or whatever else you need.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A lot of frustration and variations and that's what worked for me.
**Rails 3.2.12 Rspec 2.10**

```
 @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
 @request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
 put :update, :id => 1, "email" => "bing@test.com"
```

wrap_parameters seems to be working declared this way

```
wrap_parameters User, format: :json
```

being used for `User` model

Comment: This really tripped me up. Setting `put :update, :id => 1, :format => :json` will **not** work. You must enter as VelLes has.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me **Rails 4.0.3** and **Rspec 2.14.1** if anyone is looking for more recent versions.

```
put '/projects/1.json', {name: 'Updated Project 1'}, {
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
}
```

and

```
wrap_parameters Project, format: :json
```

Comment: I removed .to_json of params and it worked: `put '/projects/1.json', {name: 'Updated Project 1'}, {
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
}`

Answer (score 5):

Using the new Rails v5.0.x API only settings I found that this problem with rails defaulting everything to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is still in issue for testing with RSpec-Rails Requests

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

Create support file at `./spec/support/json_requests.rb`

Edit it to be something like this to override the behavior for all of your API only JSON requests:

```ruby
module JsonRequests
  def get(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def post(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def update(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def patch(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def put(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def delete(*args)
    super(*json_args(*args))
  end

  def json_args(path, params = {}, headers = {})
    [path, params.to_json, headers.merge('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json')]
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include JsonRequests, type: :request
end
```

Keep in mind that this will override all Specs within `./spec/requests` so if you need to use `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` you could also `include` this module manually as needed in your `Describe 'something' do` block.

Comment: Using ruby `2.5.0`, rails `5.1.5` and rspec `3.7.1`, I had to change the above `json_args` method to this:

`def json_args(path, params = {})`
  `[path, **params.merge(as: :json)]`
`end`

See here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5 no hacks:

```
put(:update,
    params: {project_id: 1},
    body: {name: 'Updated Project 1'}.to_json,
    as: :json)
```

This sets the `content_type` correctly. In the controller `params` will hold both params and body.

Answer (score 3):

Its 2021, Rails 6.1 and I had to use `as: :json` to fix this wierd mangling of an array of hashes in the params.

```rb
put(:update, params: the_params_hash, as: :json)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4 (and rspec ~3.7) and don't want to use the inline syntax:

```
request.headers["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5

```
headers = { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }
params = { user_type: 'tester' }
```

and after that request like

```
post '/api/v1/users/test', params.to_json, headers
```

and also remove `.to_json` from request route