# Why does 'text/html' does not count as text format in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to do is get my request unit test to enter the `format.text` block in my controller:

```
  def preview
    byebug
    respond_to do |format|
      format.text { render template: 'reporting/iue/report_mailer/report.text' }
      format.html { render template: 'reporting/iue/report_mailer/report.html' }
    end
  end
```

In my request rspec I'm passing the `as: :text` option

```
        subject(:request) do
          get api_iue_preview_path(report.id), headers: auth_headers, as: :text
        end
```

But it doesn't enter the `text` block.

I've observed that:

```
(byebug) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x007faaf921c8b0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-3118253865377356622>
(byebug) request.format.html?
true
(byebug) request.format.text?
false
```

Meaning `'text/html'` does not count as text format, but does count as an html.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: From what I see the subject should be a hash (`expect(get: 'some_path').to ...`). Try changing it to `{get: api_iue_preview_path(report.id), headers: auth_headers, as: :text}` and see if that works.

Comment: `text/html` is the correct designator for HTML content. It might look like it means "text or html" but actually it's more like "text, specifically html". The `Content-Type` you actually want is `text/plain`.

Comment: You could always provide the format option to the path instead. `api_iue_preview_path(report.id, format: :text)`

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner thank you. And how do I get a `text/plain` format?  `as: :text` didn't do it.

Comment: I'm not sure. Does this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940840/setting-content-type-header-for-rspec-and-rails-api